# mysql - how to query a table, group by name and count of titles in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to wrap my head around this query, and have tried grouping, but no luck:

If I have a table:

```
name         title         (some other fields)
John Doe     Engineer      ...
John Doe     Tech          ...
John Doe     Tech          ...
Frank Smith  Tech          ...
Frank Smith  Tech          ...
```

I need a query that would result in:

```
name         title      count(title)
John Doe     Engineer   1
John Doe     Tech       2
Frank Smith  Tech       2
```

Have tried using group by name and title, but it seems to just group one or the other, giving me the count of either total engineers (1) and techs (4), or total clients (2), but I need total titles BY name.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know why wouldn't this work:

```
SELECT name, title, COUNT(*) Titles
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY name, title
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT name , title , count(*) count
 FROM Table1
 GROUP BY name , title
 ORDER BY count
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d217/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, TITLE, COUNT(*) FROM BOOKS GROUP BY NAME, TITLE
```